# How Come Everybody Can See My Private Files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ftp, web-hosting

Sorry for the newbie question...

When I go to http://www.plans4boats.com/scripts/youtubeplayer/ in Google Chrome, I can see a full listing of the files there.  What should I do if I don't want any old hacker to just come in and view/copy my source codes?  Does it have something to do with htaccess?

I discovered that putting a blank index.html file in the folder helps for THAT folder, but it still leaves all subfolders vulnerable.

What should I google for more information on how to set up my server to prevent this?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `Options -Indexes` for that particular directories either in an `.htaccess` file or a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` container.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is turn of `Directory Listing` for your specific server.  I don't know what server you're using so I can't walk you through it, but just google your server name and how to disable directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called .htaccess and put the following contents:
IndexIgnore */*